# How to execute a sql stored procedure from Java Hibernate using Session Factory?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am unable to call my stored procedure from java hibernate using session factory

I have written a sql procedure which takes 5 parameters and return a result set which works fine in MS SQL studio

```
EXEC SlaGrid @appID=245,@fromYear=2012,@toYear=2013,@fromMon=1,@toMon=12   --- sql

EXEC SlaGrid @applID=:applID,@fromYear=:fromYear,@toYear=:toYear,@fromMon=:fromMon,@toMon=:toMon  --hibernate
```

i am setting the parameters for the above query

```
String queryString = "EXEC SlaGrid @applID=:applID,@fromYear=:fromYear,@toYear=:toYear,@fromMon=:fromMon,@toMon=:toMon"

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);

//set query parameters here

query.list()    --- giving sql grammer exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it simply by the following code...Just pass the parameters in CSV.Thanks for the help guys..

```
String queryString = "SlaGrid 245,2012,2013,1,12"

Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);

query.list();
```

Works Perfect :)

Comment: 'query.list();' did not work for me in Hibernate 4, instead I used 'query.executeUpdate()'

Comment: Does this work independently of database type or is this MySQL specific?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [callable statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/callablestatement.html) on hibernate session.

```
Connection con = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().connection();  

/**
* Amend to include your parameters and proc
*/          
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall( "{ call myprocedure }");

cs.execute();
```

Comment: Do we need to close the callablestatement? Or will session takes care of closing the callable statement.?

Answer (score 6):

create a SessionFactory and Open a session then

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = session.connection().prepareCall("call GetMarketDataCDS(?,?)");
callableStatement.setString(1,"JPM");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callableStatement.execute();
ResultSet resultSet=(ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
```

here i am using oracle and my first param is IN Parameter and second is OUT which is nothing but a resultset returning multiple rows.
Then in last line we get the ResultSet with all row and then you can iterate through the rows.

Comment: `connection()` method is deprecated, isn't it?

Comment: @Tony, use `session.doWork(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
    "CALL SlaGrid(:appID, :fromYear, :toYear, :fromMon, :toMon)")
    .setParameter("appID", 245)
    .setParameter("fromYear", 2012)
    .setParameter("toYear", 2013)
    .setParameter("fromMon", 1)
    .setParameter("toMon", 12);
```

Comment: i have tried this already ..this syntax is for mysql not mssql